# Get line numbers of fields without using a c# parser

Tags: c#, system.diagnostics, line-numbers, fieldinfo

I would like to get the line #s of a type's fields.

To get the line #'s of the statements in a method it is simple enough:

```
Type type = typeof(MyClass);
MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("SomeMethod");
int token = methodInfo.MetadataToken;
ISymbolReader reader = SymUtil.GetSymbolReaderForFile(@"dllName", null); // from mike stall's pdb2xml
ISymbolMethod methodSymbol = reader.GetMethod(new SymbolToken(token));
int count = methodSymbol.SequencePointCount;
ISymbolDocument[] docs = new ISymbolDocument[count];
int[] startColumn = new int[count];
int[] endColumn = new int[count];
int[] startRow = new int[count];
int[] endRow = new int[count];
method.GetSequencePoints(offsets, docs, startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn);
```

Unfortunately it is not enough to get a constructor's local variables, as some of the type's variables can be const/static.